# How to automatically export contacts from Thunderbird

Tags: export, thunderbird

Is there some way to export contacts from Thunderbird in CSV silently by using script, so we won't have to do it manually for every user?

My intention is to move all gathered addresses (stored in history.mab) from Thunderbird to Outlook 2013 on multiple stations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, there is probably no straight way how to do it.

I have ended up with this simple macro, which start Thunderbird and via adress book export selected contact list into CSV - far from ideal, but it works in most cases. (only works as intended with constant amount of lists)

```
SET oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

oShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"""
WScript.Sleep 10000 ' wait a bit for opening Thunderbird
oShell.SendKeys "^+b" 'open address book
WScript.Sleep 2000
oShell.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}"
oShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
oShell.SendKeys "%n"
oShell.SendKeys "x"
WScript.Sleep 2000
oShell.SendKeys "thunderbird_export_" & username & "" 'name your CSV
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
oShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}"
oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "^l"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "u:{ENTER}" 'set destination folder
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "%u"
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 1000

' close both adress book and Thunderbird
oShell.Run("taskkill /im thunderbird.exe")
WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.Run("taskkill /im thunderbird.exe")

WScript.Quit
```